# Firefox & Safari positioning using both % and px in a single definition

Tags: css, firefox, safari, css-position, percentage

A few minutes ago i stumbled upon quite a very weird phenomenon.

It seems that Firefox and Safari will not only interpret

```
left: -50%;
```

and

```
left: -50px;
```

but also

```
left: -50%px;
```

I have create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSSSE/) to demonstrate this behaviour.

Try changing the CSS for class .strangePositioner to any of the aforementioned three values and you will see different results with each.

My initial intention was to position the element to the total left of the outer div whose width is defined by the inner content (called 'stretcher' in the example). Due to accidently mistyping the CSS definition, i ended up with the correct result and then, accidently, saw that it was not a valid definition. Or so i thought.

Q: Why are the browsers interpreting this the way they do and is it (aside from syntax issues) valid CSS? If it is not valid CSS, what standard does it not comply with?

Comment: I am seeing both Div's align to the left of the container div, it would be good to have an image of what I should be seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just looking at your jsfiddle and was able to get BOOM to align to the left by simply omitting any left argument, or using left: 0;

Therefore I'm going to conclude that FF and Safari see your %px and treat the line as invalid, thereby leaving the default value of left: auto (0)

And if you check it out using firebug computed values, you'll see there's no left defined on the element, it's inheriting left: auto;

BOOM!

Answer (score 1):

`left: -50%px;` is not valid css, use either `%` or `px`

Answer (score 0):

I observed the results and played around with it a bit. Strange how changing the `top` value can actualy influence the left position. Also i sometimes got different results with the same code. Definitly no valid css http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/. Would not count on it to behave predictable, defintly not cross browser. My advice would be to stick to valid css!

Comment: Its pretty interesting, yeah. I decided to use it as it is only needed inside my CMS and that's FF only anyway. I would classify this as sort of a hack then.

Comment: i would classify it as a bug and not count on it. As said, chrome gave me different results for the same code sometimes. And what if FF fixes this 'bug' tomorrow? What you try to achieve should be perfectly possible with valid, cross browser, css. (and you should consider switching to chrome, much faster then ff and all the same features or better)

Comment: check firebug, or my answer I just posted...  it's simply ignoring the line and left: auto is being inherit into the element

Answer (score 0):

Its not valid CSS and a valid CSS parser like the ones in most browsers will drop the declaration and use the default or inherited left value instead. You shouldn't use it because I have the same results in every browser I try so its possible the results your seeing are specific to your set-up and can change with the next firefox update.

Below is an image of the results I got in FF(14), Safari, Chrome(21)

[image: All browser results]

Comment: This is the correct result - the intended one. What do you get when you use -50% only or -50px only? The latter is clear. And -50% should move the BOOM!-Container out of sight.

Comment: Correct, This is the default left value `left:auto;` and occurs because the left value of `left: -50%px;` is dropped and ignored.